# New auto-detecting key/value arguments - What it is for?

Tags: api

In LaTeX News, Issues 1–36, it is written:

> Auto-detecting key/value arguments
> To allow extension of the core LATEX syntax, `ltcmd` now supports a `=...` modifier when grabbing arguments. This modifier instructs LATEX that the argument should be passed to the underlying code as a set of key/values. If the argument does not “look like” a set of key/values, it will be converted into a single key/value pair, with the argument to `=` specifying the name of that key. For example, the \caption command could be defined as
> `\DeclareDocumentCommand\caption {s ={short-text}+O{#3} +m}{...}`

What is the API utility of this kind of feature?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have an existing command like

```
\section[short version]{long version of title}
```

and would like to get to a key/val future

```
\section[pdfoutline=very short, page-head=quite short,
        toc=medium length]{long version of title}
```

this gives you a way to support both syntaxes by spotting there is no `=` in

```
  \section[short version]{long version of title}
```

and defining it to mean

```
\section[toc=short version]{long version of title}
```

---

[image]

Here I show a debug definition that shows how the argument `#2` is always exposed as a keyval list even if the legacy form `\section[short version]` is used, so this allows new functionality with multiple keys to be defined.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\section {s ={short-text}+O{#3} +m}{%
\par
\bigskip
Section:\par
\IfBooleanTF{#1}%
   {no number}%
   {number}\par
options: \texttt{\detokenize{#2}}\par
main text:  \texttt{\detokenize{#3}}\par 
}


\begin{document}

\section{aaaa}

\section*[short text]{a section}

\section[toc=a sec., 
         page-head =this text, 
         pdfbookmark= A SECTION]{another section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, it remains to parse the keys, and the value as usual. So this is a good feature.

Comment: @projetmbc I added an example

Comment: @projetmbc yes it just sets up the input, you can use `keyval` or `l3keys` or `pgf` or whatever to actually process the keys

Comment: @barbarabeeton done

Comment: This assumes that all keys have to be followed by an = sign, and seems so exclude section titles containing = signs, at least in their short titles.

Comment: @gandolf you can have Boolean keys with no value as long as they are not the only key on an instance. you can have = so long it is in a brace or $ group  if you take an existing command such as section or caption and extend its syntax there are always theoretical possibilities of clashes, we tried several things and this seemed the most reasonable balance.

Comment: This assumes that the user did precisely what you think they do. Any user who did something extraordinary on their own will be at a great risk of having their older documents throwing errors. Really hope that experiments like this do not become part of the kernel.